# How do I initialise state values and methods that uses useSyncExternalStore + Context in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state, react-state-management

### Description

I'm creating a state management tool for a small project, using mainly `useSyncExternalStore` from React, inspired by this video from Jack Herrington https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKlXqrcBx88&ab_channel=JackHerrington.

But, I'm running into a pattern that doesn't look right, which is having to use 2 providers, one to create the state, and the other to initialise it.

###### The gist of the problem:

I have a property `sessionId` coming from an HTTP request. Saving it in my store wasn't an issue.

However, once I have a `sessionId` then all of my POST requests done with `notifyBackend` should have this `sessionId` in the request body. And I was able to achieve this requirement using the pattern above, but I don't like it.

Any idea how to make it better ?

### Code

**CreateStore.jsx** (Not important, just providing the code in case)

```
export default function createStore(initialState) {
    function useStoreData(): {
        const store = useRef(initialState);
        const subscribers = useRef(new Set());

        return {
            get: useCallback(() => store.current, []),
            set: useCallback((value) => {
                store.current = { ...store.current, ...value };
                subscribers.current.forEach((callback) => callback());
            }, []),
            subscribe: useCallback((callback) => {
                subscribers.current.add(callback);
                return () => subscribers.current.delete(callback);
            }, []),
        };
    }

    const StoreContext = createContext(null);
    function StoreProvider({ children }) {
        return (
            <StoreContext.Provider value={useStoreData()}>
                {children}
            </StoreContext.Provider>
        );
    }

    function useStore(selector) {
        const store = useContext(StoreContext);
        const state = useSyncExternalStore(
            store.subscribe,
            () => selector(store.get()),
            () => selector(initialState),
        );

        // [value, appendToStore]
        return [state, store.set];
    }

    return {
        StoreProvider,
        useStore,
    };
}
```

**Creating the state**

```
export const { StoreProvider, useStore } = createStore({
    sessionId: "INITIAL",
    notifyBackend: () => { },
});
```

**index.jsx**

```
<Router>
  <StoreProvider>
    <InitialisationProvider>
      <App />
    </InitialisationProvider>
  </StoreProvider>
</Router
```

**InitialisationContext.jsx**

```
const InitialisationContext = createContext({});

export const InitializationProvider = ({ children }) {
  const [sessionId, appendToStore] = useStore(store => store.session);
  const notifyBackend = async({ data }) => {
    const _data = {
      ...data,
      sessionId,
    };
    try {
      const result = await fetchPOST(data);
      if (result.sessionId) {
        appendToStore({ sessionId: result.sessionId });
      } else if (result.otherProp) {
        appendToStore({ otherProp: result.otherProp });
      }
    } catch (e) { }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    appendToStore({ notifyBackend });
  }, [sessionId]);

  return (
    <InitialisationContext.Provider value={{}}>
      {children}
    </InitialisationContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Without ill intent, how is any of the things you're trying to do here related to anything later seen on the screen? .... if it's not, then react may be the wrong place to manage these things. Does any of your components really need to know the current sessionId? or be notified/rerendered when it changes?

Comment: In your question, `notifyBackend` feels like a logger of sorts notifying the backend about things the user does in the frontend, but from your answer regarding zustand I get more the feeling that it's only purpose is to make an initial ajax call to get the sessionId for subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @Thomas
I tried to over-simplify what `notifyBackend` does, in fact, it sends a POST request to the backend passing a `command` (`"add" | "delete" | ...`) and a `sessionId` (`"initial" | "<unique session id>"`) if the command is `"add"` or `"delete"` I'll receive back a shopping list response, if the command is something else, I'll receive back a totally different response. This is a legacy behaviour that I have no control over at the moment.
But my main issue is telling `notifyBackend` that the sessionId is `state.sessionId` or like in zustand `get().sessionId`

Answer (score 1):

*This answer focuses on OPs approach to `createStore()`. After reading the question a few more times, I think there are bigger issues. I'll try to get to these and then extend the answer.*

---

Your approach is too complicated.

First, the store is no hook! It lives completely outside of react. `useSyncExternalStore` and the two methods `subscribe` and `getSnapshot` are what integrates the store into react.

And as the store lives outside of react, you don't need a Context at all.
Just do `const whatever = useSyncExternalStore(myStore.subscribe, myStore.getSnapshot);`

Here my version of minimal `createStore()` basically a global/shared `useState()`

```
export function createStore(initialValue) {
  // subscription
  const listeners = new Set();
  const subscribe = (callback) => {
    listeners.add(callback);
    return () => listeners.delete(callback);
  }
  const dispatch = () => {
    for (const callback of listeners) callback();
  }

  // value management
  let value = typeof initialValue === "function" ? 
    initialValue() : 
    initialValue;

  // this is what useStore() will return.
  const getSnapshot = () => [value, setState];

  // the same logic as in `setState(newValue)` or `setState(prev => newValue)`
  const setState = (arg) => {
    let prev = value;
    value = typeof arg === "function" ? arg(prev) : arg;
    if (value !== prev) dispatch(); // only notify listener on actual change.
  }

  // returning just a custom hook
  return () => useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot);
}
```

And the usage

```
export const useMyCustomStore = createStore({});

// ...

const [value, setValue] = useMyCustomStore();
```

Comment: can you share the code of useMyCustomStore?

Comment: @cesarpachon it's defined like 2 lines higher?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out Zustand, and it's very similar to what I'm trying to achieve.
Feels like I'm trying to reinvent the wheel.

With Zustand:

**main-store.js**

```js
import create from 'zustand';

export const useMainStore = create((set, get) => ({
  sessionId: 'INITIAL',
  otherProp: '',
  notifyBackend: async ({ data }) => {
    const _data = {
      ...data,
      sessionId: get().sessionId,
    };
    try {
      const result = await fetchPOST(data);
      if (result.sessionId) {
        set({ sessionId: result.sessionId });
      } else if (result.otherProp) {
        set({ otherProp: result.otherProp });
      }
    } catch (e) { }
  },
}));
```

**SomeComponent.jsx**

```
export const SomeComponent() {
  const sessionId = useMainStore(state => state.sessionId);
  const notifyBackend = useMainStore(state => state.notifyBackend);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sessionId === 'INITIAL') {
      notifyBackend();
    }
  }, [sessionId]);

  return <h1>Foo</h1>
};
```